# Take off XmlRootElement

Tags: java, jaxb, xmlroot

I´m making a request. I should return a String.

My Answer should be:

```
    <GETSOMETHING>
      <result>
         1
      </result>
   </GETSOMETHING>
```

My atually answer is this:

```
<GETSOMETHING>
<Nothing here>
  <result>
     1
  </result>
</Nothing here>
</GETSOMETHING>
```

My Wrapper class:

```
@XmlRootElement(name="Nothing here")
public class Result_Response_WRAPPER_XML_Object implements Serializable {

    private String fields = "";

    public Result_Response_WRAPPER_XML_Object () {
    }


    @XmlElement(name="result")
    public String getFields() {
        return fields;
    }


    public void setFields(String fields) {
        this.fields = fields;
    }

}
```

My Web Service is this:

//Web Method should return a String.

```
@WebMethod(operationName = "get_result")
    @Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_XML)
    public void get_result(@WebParam(name = "requests") RequestObject obj,
            @WebParam(name = "GETSOMETHING", mode = WebParam.Mode.OUT) Holder<String> response,
             {

            //Call my string from class Operation
            String result= operation.getResult(obj);
```

How to get rid off  tag?

Comment: Have you tried removing the `@XmlRootElement(name="Nothing here")` annotation?

Comment: He needs XmlRootElement

Comment: I know that. But looks like GETSOMETHING is already the root of the document.

Comment: I´m using marshal. For that reason my wrapper class should have @XmlRootElement